# Please help me to figure out how to display my tags

Tags: tags, template-tags

desperately looking for help. Have a Wordpress theme which does not display post tags on a single page and I badly need to have them there. Developers only named a file which needs to be modified. It's "content-single.php" My site is http://nepyragas.eu/ I can post all code here if needed.

Kindly help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP function the_tags(), [more info here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags).

You will have to figure out where exactly in your content-single.php to put this but you want to add something like this...

```
<p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
```

View the link above for more examples.